# NHibernate get wrong datetime range

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In the NHibernate + Oracle, a query is generated

```
SELECT *
FROM mytbl this_ 
WHERE this_.PRICING_DATE >= :p0 and this_.PRICING_DATE <= :p1 
:p0 = 7/25/2012 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p1 = 7/26/2012 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)]
```

why this query will return data on 7/26/2012 ? what I want is to get data on 7/25.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you give an example of the records it returns?

Comment: I always thought you should pass in `7/25/2012 00:00:00` NOT 12:00:00AM as that is midday not midnight, unless orcale is different to MsSql

Comment: @Rippo I don't know mySql, but 12:00:00AM IS MIDNIGHT, not NOON.  It is conceptually the moment after the previous day.  Because the number is an instant (not a duration or time interval), it can be confusing as to which side of the meridian the 12:00 instant should fall.  Think about it this way, 12:01 AM is morning not the afternoon.  So to be consistent, we need to be a little inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because 7/26/2012 is == to 7/26/2012 12:00:00 AM.  You should use < :p1.  Even then, I vaguely recall that time at around 12 midnight (in SQL) has some fractional issues.  Try <=, but let :p1 = 7/25/2012 11:59:59 PM